# Upgraded debian from bullseye to bookworm and now the computer freezes at boot screen

Tags: debian, system-installation, upgrade

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade) to upgrade debian bullseye to debian bookworm but now my computer freezes at the boot screen on the line "Loading initial ramdisk ...".

[image]

Can someone help me diagnose and resolve this issue?

My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad L590.

---

EDIT

Potential missing firmware warnings after running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 6.1.0-13-amd64`:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_03.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adls_dmc_ver2_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_16.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_dmc_ver2_07.bin for module i915
```

In case it is relevant this is what my `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like. As you can see I added the `non-free-firmware` tag:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.7.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20230429-11:50]/ bullseye contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.7.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20230429-11:50]/ bullseye contrib main

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
# deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
# deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib

# bullseye-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm contrib main non-free-firmware non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm contrib main non-free-firmware non-free#Added by software-properties
```

Comment: 1. Where there any issues reported during the upgrade? 2. Do you have a backup?

Comment: I don't remember seeing any errors at least. I did make a backup in case I need to install fresh. Rather not do that though if possible.

Comment: You could check if stopping the default kernel boot, selecting advanced in GRUB's menus and booting the previous kernel (5.10.x along its own initramfs/initrd) might still work. Should it work, do a backup of /boot (at least this previous kernel and its initrd file) too just in case before it gets a chance to get updated.

Comment: @A.B Thanks. Booting the previous kernel worked. I made a backup of /boot but am I supposed to now do something to make the new kernel work?

Comment: I'm leaving this to somebody else. Your issue could be a hardware/driver/compatibility problem, or a (new) initrd not updated correctly I don't know. But at least for now you have your system which is an improvement.

Comment: In case it was initrd not generated correctly, check there's space available in /boot (say at least 70mb) and rebuild the newer initrd/initramfs (while making sure to not rebuild the older) with: `update-initramfs -u -k 6.1.0-13-amd64`. Verify no error is displayed. Then reboot and see if it works any better.

Comment: @A.B I get a lot of possible missing firmware warnings but no errors

Comment: No success rebooting with the new kernel. I put the output of the update-initramfs in the original post

Comment: I installed the missing firmware and reran `update-initramfs -u -k 6.1.0-13-amd64` and there were no errors nor warnings. Still not booting however.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a different virtual console (i.e. pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2) and waiting to see if a text-mode login prompt will appear? If that does not happen, then the next troubleshooting step could be to use GRUB to temporarily edit out the default `quiet` boot option, which should cause a lot of messages to be displayed in the boot process. Those might help in identifying the problem.

Comment: I was able to fix it!! I had to update my BIOS